# How to avoid equation from touching h-lines in tables

Tags: tables

I have lengthy equations in table and I want to avoid these equations from touching table horizontal lines. I have used struts for this purpose but first row it seems that struts are not working as desired. Following is my Latex code

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preprint,10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}}%to get pdf zoomed to 100%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}%to automaticaly break math equation using \begin{dmath}.........\end{dmath}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''}%for adding double quotes like "quotes"
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]% various theorems, numbered by section
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem{red}{Reduction}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}%this package can be used to create new line within table cell using \makecell{line 1 \\ line2}
\usepackage{chngcntr}%for changing counter
    \usepackage{chngcntr}%for changing counter
    \counterwithin{case}{red}%number given to case within reduction, for this \usepackage{chngcntr} is necessary
    \counterwithin{red}{section}
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}% equations can be numbered within section
    \journal{Acta Applicandae Mathematicae}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
         colorlinks   = true,
         citecolor    = gray
    }%to assign color to hyperlink
    \usepackage[margin=1in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}
    \usepackage{url}
    %\usepackage{pdfsync}
    \usepackage{srcltx}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}%for cursive font
    \begin{document}
    \begin{flushleft}
      \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
      \newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{3.6ex}} % Top strut
    \newcommand\B{\rule[-3.6ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
         \hline\hline
         Element $w_{i}$ in 1--dimensional sub--algebra $\Theta_{1}$\T\B&Nor$\left(w_{i}\right)$&$\mathscr{H}\left(w_{i}, w\right)\left(w\in\text{Nor}\left(w_{i}\right)/w_{i}\right)$\\
         \hline\hline
         $w_{1}=\,a_{3}V_{3}+a_{9}V_{9}+a_{10}V_{10}+V_{11}$ \T\B&$\begin{aligned}&\frac{2a_{9}^2}{(a_{3}-a_{10})(a_{3}-2a_{10})}V_{1}+a_{3}V_{3}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{7}+\frac{a_{3}a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{9}+V_{11},\\ &\frac{2a_{9}^{2}}{a_{10}(a_{3}-a_{10})(a_{3}-2a_{10})}V_{1}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{10}(a_{3}-a_{10})}V_{7}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{9}-V_{10}\end{aligned}$\T\B&$\begin{aligned}\mathscr{H}_{1}\left(w_{1}, \frac{2a_{9}^2}{(a_{3}-a_{10})(a_{3}-2a_{10})}V_{1}+a_{3}V_{3}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{7}+\frac{a_{3}a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{9}+V_{11}\right),\\\mathscr{H}_{1}^{\prime}\left(w_{1},
         \frac{2a_{9}^{2}}{a_{10}(a_{3}-a_{10})(a_{3}-2a_{10})}V_{1}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{10}(a_{3}-a_{10})}V_{7}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{9}-V_{10} \right)\end{aligned}$\T\B\\
         \hline
         $w_{2}=\,a_{3}V_{3}+V_{10}$&$V_{3}, V_{10}$\T\B&$\mathscr{H}_{2}(w_{2}, V_{3})$\\
         \hline
         $w_{3}=a_{{2}}V_{{2}}+V_{{3}}+a_{{5}}V_{{5}}+a_{{8}}V_{{8}}+a_{{9}}V_{{9}}+V_{{10}}$\T\B&$V_{3}+V_{10}, \frac{a_{2}}{a_{9}}V_{2}+\frac{a_{2}a_{5}-a_{2}a_{8}-2a_{8}a_{9}}{a_{2}a_{9}}V_{5}+V_{9}, \frac{a_{2}+2a_{9}}{a_{2}}V_{5}+V_{8},V_{4}$&$\mathscr{H}_{3}\left(w_{3}, V_{4}\right)$\\
         \hline
         $w_{4}=V_{{3}}+a_{{4}}V_{{4}}+a_{{5}}V_{{5}}+a_{{8}}V_{{8}}+a_{{9}}V_{{9}}+V_{{10}}$\T\B&$V_{5}, V_{4}, V_{3}+V_{10}, \frac{a_{8}}{a_{9}}V_{8}+V_{9}$&{Null}\\
         \hline
         $w_{5}=\frac{1}{2}V_{3}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{10}$\T\B&$\frac{1}{3}V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{6}$&{Null}\\
         \hline
         $w_{6}=a_{{1}}V_{{1}}+2\,V_{{3}}+V_{{10}}$\T\B&$2V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{1}$&Null\\
         \hline
         $w_{7}=a_{3}V_{3}+V_{7}$\T\B&$V_{3}, V_{7}$&{Null}\\
         \hline
         $w_{8}=V_{2}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}$\T\B&$a_{5}V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8}+a_{6}V_{11},V_{2}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, 3V_{4}+a_{6}V_{7}, V_{1}$&$\mathscr{H}_{8}^{(1)}\left(w_{1},a_{5}V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8}+a_{6}V_{11}\right), \mathscr{H}_{8}^{(2)}\left(w_{1},3V_{4}+a_{6}V_{7}\right), \mathscr{H}_{8}^{(3)}\left(w_{1},V_{1}\right)$\\
         \hline
         $w_{9}=a_{4}V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}$\T\B&$(a_{5}a_{8}-a_{4})V_{4}-a_{6}V_{6}+a_{6}a_{8}V_{11}, a_{4}V_{4}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, 2V_{4}+a_{6}V_{7}, V_{5}, V_{1}$&$\begin{aligned}&\mathscr{H}_{9}^{(1)}\left(w_{1},(a_{5}a_{8}-a_{4})V_{4}-a_{6}V_{6}+a_{6}a_{8}V_{11}\right), \mathscr{H}_{9}^{(2)}\left(w_{1}, a_{4}V_{4}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}\right),\\ &\mathscr{H}_{9}^{(3)}\left(w_{1}, 2V_{4}+a_{6}V_{7}\right), \mathscr{H}_{9}^{(4)}\left(w_{1}, V_{5}\right), \mathscr{H}_{9}^{(5)}\left(w_{1}, V_{1}\right)\end{aligned}$\\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}}\captionof{table}{Two dimensional sub--algebra from normalizer.}\label{table3}
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). But, please complete it by including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Are the equations in the tabular really necessary?

Comment: Yes, writing equations in table is most judicious for me to save space in article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equations are not readable without magnifying glass ...

but this apparently is not the question. To make equations at least slightly bigger I suggest to reduce the inter column space, omit spaces on the beginning and the end of table. Also struts T and B, which has influence only in rows with equations in one line, can be simply replaced by increasing `\arraystretch`. Further simplification of your MWE is possible with use of `array` instead of `tabular` environment. With this you spare to write `$` sign at each equations.

So for solving your problem are left two cells. There it seems to be the simplest hack to add empty lines in `aligned` environments like:

```
\begin{aligned}
        ~\\[-2ex]    % <--- added empty line
        &\frac{2a_{9}^2}{(a_{3}-a_{10})(a_{3}-2a_{10})}V_{1}+a_{3}V_{3}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{7}+\frac{a_{3}a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{9}+V_{11},\\ &\frac{2a_{9}^{2}}{a_{10}(a_{3}-a_{10})(a_{3}-2a_{10})}V_{1}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{10}(a_{3}-a_{10})}V_{7}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{9}-V_{10}
        \\[-2ex]~   % <--- added empty line
        \end{aligned}
```

With mentioned measure I obtain:

[image]

The complete relevant code is:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preprint,10pt]{elsarticle}
    \usepackage[margin=1in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in,showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{srcltx}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}%for cursive font
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}%to automaticaly break math equation using \begin{dmath}.........\end{dmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}%this package can be used to create new line within table cell using \makecell{line 1 \\ line2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00},%to get pdf zoomed to 100% 
    colorlinks   = true,
    citecolor    = gray
    }%to assign color to hyperlink

    \begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
      \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{3.6ex}} % Top strut
\newcommand\B{\rule[-3.6ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%1.2
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
$    \begin{array}{@{}l|l|l@{}}
         \hline\hline
\text{Element } w_{i} \text{ in 1--dimensional sub--algebra} \Theta_{1}
    &   \text{Nor}\left(w_{i}\right)
        &   \mathscr{H}\left(w_{i}, w\right)\left(w\in\text{Nor}\left(w_{i}\right)/w_{i}\right)\\
         \hline\hline
w_{1}=\,a_{3}V_{3}+a_{9}V_{9}+a_{10}V_{10}+V_{11}
    &   \begin{aligned}
        ~\\[-2ex]
        &\frac{2a_{9}^2}{(a_{3}-a_{10})(a_{3}-2a_{10})}V_{1}+a_{3}V_{3}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{7}+\frac{a_{3}a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{9}+V_{11},\\ &\frac{2a_{9}^{2}}{a_{10}(a_{3}-a_{10})(a_{3}-2a_{10})}V_{1}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{10}(a_{3}-a_{10})}V_{7}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{9}-V_{10}
        \\[-2ex]~
        \end{aligned}
    &   \begin{aligned}\mathscr{H}_{1}\left(w_{1},
            \frac{2a_{9}^2}{(a_{3}-a_{10})(a_{3}-2a_{10})}V_{1}+a_{3}V_{3}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{7}+\frac{a_{3}a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{9}+V_{11}\right),\\\mathscr{H}_{1}^{\prime}\left(w_{1},
         \frac{2a_{9}^{2}}{a_{10}(a_{3}-a_{10})(a_{3}-2a_{10})}V_{1}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{10}(a_{3}-a_{10})}V_{7}+\frac{a_{9}}{a_{3}-a_{10}}V_{9}-V_{10}\right)
         \end{aligned}\\
         \hline
w_{2}=\,a_{3}V_{3}+V_{10}
    &   V_{3}, V_{10}&\mathscr{H}_{2}(w_{2}, V_{3})\\
         \hline
w_{3}=a_{{2}}V_{{2}}+V_{{3}}+a_{{5}}V_{{5}}+a_{{8}}V_{{8}}+a_{{9}}V_{{9}}+V_{{10}}
    &   V_{3}+V_{10}, \frac{a_{2}}{a_{9}}V_{2}+\frac{a_{2}a_{5}-a_{2}a_{8}-2a_{8}a_{9}}{a_{2}a_{9}}V_{5}+V_{9}, \frac{a_{2}+2a_{9}}{a_{2}}V_{5}+V_{8},V_{4}
        &   \mathscr{H}_{3}\left(w_{3}, V_{4}\right)\\
         \hline
w_{4}=V_{{3}}+a_{{4}}V_{{4}}+a_{{5}}V_{{5}}+a_{{8}}V_{{8}}+a_{{9}}V_{{9}}+V_{{10}}
    &   V_{5}, V_{4}, V_{3}+V_{10}, \frac{a_{8}}{a_{9}}V_{8}+V_{9}
        &   {Null}\\
         \hline
w_{5}=\frac{1}{2}V_{3}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{10}
    &   \frac{1}{3}V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{6}
        &   {Null}\\
         \hline
w_{6}=a_{{1}}V_{{1}}+2\,V_{{3}}+V_{{10}}
    &   2V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{1}
        &   Null    \\
         \hline
w_{7}=a_{3}V_{3}+V_{7}
    &   V_{3}, V_{7}&{Null}\\
         \hline
w_{8}=V_{2}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}
    &   a_{5}V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8}+a_{6}V_{11},V_{2}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, 3V_{4}+a_{6}V_{7}, V_{1}
        &   \mathscr{H}_{8}^{(1)}\left(w_{1},a_{5}V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8}+a_{6}V_{11}\right), \mathscr{H}_{8}^{(2)}\left(w_{1},3V_{4}+a_{6}V_{7}\right), \mathscr{H}_{8}^{(3)}\left(w_{1},V_{1}\right)\\
         \hline
w_{9}=a_{4}V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}
    &   (a_{5}a_{8}-a_{4})V_{4}-a_{6}V_{6}+a_{6}a_{8}V_{11}, a_{4}V_{4}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, 2V_{4}+a_{6}V_{7}, V_{5}, V_{1}
        &   \begin{aligned}
            ~\\[-2ex]
            &\mathscr{H}_{9}^{(1)}\left(w_{1},(a_{5}a_{8}-a_{4})V_{4}-a_{6}V_{6}+a_{6}a_{8}V_{11}\right), \mathscr{H}_{9}^{(2)}\left(w_{1}, a_{4}V_{4}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}\right),\\ &\mathscr{H}_{9}^{(3)}\left(w_{1}, 2V_{4}+a_{6}V_{7}\right), \mathscr{H}_{9}^{(4)}\left(w_{1}, V_{5}\right), \mathscr{H}_{9}^{(5)}\left(w_{1}, V_{1}\right)
            \\[-2ex]~
            \end{aligned}\\
         \hline
    \end{array}$
}
\captionof{table}{Two dimensional sub--algebra from normalizer.}
    \label{table3}
\end{flushleft}
    \end{document}
```

As you can see, I also changing column type from `c` to `l`. This gives form which I more like and hasn't any influence in vertical spacing of equations.

**Edit:**
To above solution are possible more alternatives. For example:

- not use vertical lines and instead `\hline` use `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` from `booktabs` package
- instead `array` use `mdwtab` packages with `hlx{vhv}` or `\hlx{vvhvv}` lines and `Mc` or `Ml` column types.

In this cases you not need hack with empty lines in multi line equations.

Comment: The package `booktab` is very useful, but I guess this do not work with `longtable` , when I use `\toprule`, `\bottomrule` and `\midrule`, the `longtable` extend beyond vertical margin.

Comment: I very doubt that this is caused by `booktabs` package. For solution search through SE for similar problem or ask new question.

Comment: It  is resolved by placing `package` `booktab` before `longtable`